# VBA Weekday function returns different value from Excel Weekday function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm completely stumped -

Using the `Weekday()` function in vba is returning the incorrect weekday, while using it within a sheet in Excel is returning the correct weekday. Specifying or omitting the start-of-week arguments does not seem to be making any difference either.

The system clock (which is what I assume it uses for 'today') has not been changed. In fact, I don't even have access to change it.

This is what my immediate window in VBA returned:

```
Print Weekdayname(Weekday(today),False)
Saturday

Print Weekday(today)
 7 

Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Weekday(today)
 7 

Print Weekday(6/5/2014)
 7 

Print Weekday(6/13/2014)
 7
```

The excel sheet, on the other hand, returns 5 for these formulas:

```
=WEEKDAY(TODAY())
=WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE("06/5/2014"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

I am using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is "today" will not return anything.  Use "now":

```
Weekdayname(Weekday(Now),False)
```

Also, for your last functions where you are inputting the date, you need to put it in quotes:

```
Weekday("6/5/2014")
```

Comment: Newbie mistakes :/  thanks very much.

I am still surprised though that it returned 7 - VBA often does different things with zero-length strings, and the fact that it defaulted to 7 (saturday) without that output being noted in the method's help text is odd to me.

Comment: The equivalent VBA/Excel functions are =NOW()/Now and =TODAY() /Date. So `Weekday(Date)` will also work. Today is not a function in VBA.

Answer (score 3):

You try to display the weekday of a Date serial number that's result of the calculation `6/5/2014` (i.e. 6 divided by 5 then divided by 2014).

If you want to use literal values of type Date, try in your Immediate window:

```
?Weekday(#6/5/2014#)
```

Please note the difference between this and:

```
?Weekday(6/5/2014)
```